# How to find a key in a HashMap that is mapped to a List<String> value containing the given string

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a ***map*** with a *pet owner's name* for *key* and a `List` of *pets* for a *value*.

I want to get the names of the people who have a *hamster*.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("dog");
map.put("Pesho", list);

list.clear();
list.add("dog");
list.add("cat");
map.put("Anne", list);

list.clear();
list.add("iguana");
list.add("hamster");
list.add("turtle");
map.put("Kate", list);

 // The stream only returns if someone in the map has a hamster
System.out.println(map.values().stream()
                      .anyMatch(pets -> pets.contains("hamster")));
```

Comment: Iterate through the entrySet of the map and return the keys of those entries where the value matches your search criteria.

Comment: Do you have a lot of data? How many Strings are there altogether in all the Lists?

Answer (score 3):

Iteration needs to be done over the ***entry set*** or over the ***key set***, it is impossible to access a *key* when have only a *value*.

Operation `anyMatch()` returns a `boolean` value. You need to use either `findFirst()` to get a single result, or `collect()` to obtain a *collection* of names. In both cases, the predicate from the `anyMatch()` needs to be placed into the `filter()` operation.

Terminal operation `findFirst()` returns  `Optional` because a result might not be present. You can extract a value from the optional in different ways, for instance, by applying `get()`, but in the case of empty optional it'll throw `NoSuchElementException`. In the example below, method `orElse()` is used to provide a default value.

```
String name =
        map.entrySet().stream() // stream of map-entries
                    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains("hamster"))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse("no owner was found");
```

Operation `collect()` expects as a parameter `Collector` (*an object that is responsible for populating a mutable container, like a collection with elements of the stream*).

```
List<String> names =
       map.keySet().stream() // stream of owner names
                   .filter(key -> map.get(key).contains("hamster"))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());  // Or `toList()` in Java 16+.
```

**Note:**

- When the two entries in your code will share the *same list*. Instead of invoking `list.clear();` need to create a ***new list*** so that every key will correspond to a distinct collection of pet-names.
- Search will be more performant if you replace an `ArrayList` with a `HashSet` (i.e. *map* will be declared as `Map<String,Set<String>>`).

Comment: Did you mean to use [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny()) rather than [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst())?

Comment: @BasilBourque Both will do, and with a sequential stream both will return the same element or empty optional. Behavior will differ only in parallel. And I guess OP rather wants to obtain a collection of names, but the title mentions a single key, so I decided to include an option with a single name as well.